# App Engine Cloud Storage RequestPayloadTooLargeException file exceeded the 10 MB limit

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We are trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage on App Engine Standard Java 7.

Everything is working fine, except for files larger than 10 MB. When we attempt to upload such files, we get an exception:

```
com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.RequestPayloadTooLargeException: The request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/filestoragetradeos1/o?projection=full&uploadType=multipart exceeded the 10 MiB limit.
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:151)
at
```

The code we use to do that:

```
public Blob createFile(String fileName, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    String bucketName = TSystemUtils.getStorageBucketName();//just a bucket name

    List<Acl> acls = new ArrayList<>();
    acls.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllAuthenticatedUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));

    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);//apache IO library
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    Blob blob = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, (UUID.randomUUID() + "/" + fileName)).setAcl(acls).build(), bytes);

    return blob;
}
```

Now the URL Fetch is used by App Engine to execute all the HTTP requests and it has a [10 MB Request size limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/outbound-requests#quotas_and_limits_for_url_fetch).

Is there a way to upload files larger than that on App Engine Standard Java 7 to Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to upload large files to Cloud Storage from client. Your App Engine app will generate a signed URL and pass it to the client to initiate the upload. You can even easily implement [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload)